# Getting NullPointerException when accessing spinner of another class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I have two classes `Settings` and `MainActivity`. I am trying to access a spinner created at the `Settings` class from the `MainActivity` class.

This usually works

```
public static Settings getlang = new Settings();
```

The problem is, If I try to do this without opening the Settings activity first and directly going into the MainActivity I get the NullPointerException at this line

```
getlang.getLang1().setSelection(getlang.getLang());
```

But If I first open the `Settings` activity and then go to `MainActivity` everything works fine.

How can I fix this?

Here is the `Settings` activity

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    public SharedPreferences prefsSet;
    public String prefNameSet = "MyPrefSet";

    public static final String PREFS_NAME_SET = "SAVEDATASET";

    private static final String SPINNER1_STATE = "spinner1_state";

    public int language;

    public int userChoice;

    private static Spinner spinner1;
    private Button savesett;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        savesett = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveSett);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner", -1);
        if (spinnerValue != -1)
            // set the value of the spinner
            spinner1.setSelection(spinnerValue);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userChoice = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                        0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner", userChoice);
                prefEditor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(
                        parent.getContext(),
                        "Chosen Language: "
                                + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        savesett.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            }

        });
    }

    public int getLang() {

        return userChoice;}

        public Spinner getLang1() {

            return Settings.spinner1;
    }


}
```

Comment: with out creating a view.... you want to access that view

Comment: whats you requirement ???? y do you want to access a view is not been even rreated in another activity.... ???

Comment: you will not be able to access the spinner from main activity if settings is never opened, because the spinner will never have been instantiated. Change the way you want to access elements from one activity to another, or implement another idea. You will not always be present to inform users what screen to go to first. They will use the app as they wish.

Answer (score 2):

From your code I can assume (or may be guess) that *you are using the **Spinner** in the **Settings.class** to **select the Language of the user*** & you are also saving it in the **SharedPreferences**.xml.

So, now **instead of getting the value of the spinner from the Spinner object, just read it from the SharedPreferences.xml**. Even if you are not doing so, I think this is the best way to approach your problem.

Now when you open the app for the first time & that there is no Preferences set for the language you can *set a default value (say English)*. **When the user changes the language from the Settings spinner, you can save it in the SharedPreferences and then read it from your MainActivity.class**.

**Code for working with Shared Preferences :**

***--> For Writing Data to Shared Preferences :***

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

// Saving Data to Shared Preferences
editor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner", 1);
editor.commit();
```

***--> For Reading Data from Shared Preferences :***

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int spinner_value = prefs.getInt("userChoiceSpinner", -1); // Here -1 is the default value to return when there is no value for the key "userChoiceSpinner" in the Shared Preferences.
```

Comment: Yes that is what im trying to do. I have no idea how i can create a sharedpreferences.xml. Can you give an example?

Comment: This didnt really work. I put the Writing Data to SharedPreferences part in the onCreate of Settings and the Reading Data from Shared Preferences to the onCreate of MainActivity. I ther tried to read the spinner value with getlang.getLang1().getItemAtPosition(spinner_value) It did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you do not need to read the value of the Spinner using the method "getlang.getLang1().getItemAtPosition(spinner_value)". You just need to read it from the Shared Preferences.

Comment: Your code in the Settings.class is fine. Add these lines of code in your MainActivity.class to read the value of the Spinner. `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
  
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_spinner);
  tv.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner", -1))); `

Answer (score 0):

By not creating an instance of Spinner, `spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);` never runs.

You'll have to do something like this:

Make a method:

```
    public static void setSpinner(int id){
        spinner=findViewById(id);
    }
```

and run it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create an instance of activity class

```
   public static Settings getlang = new Settings(); // wrong
```

Activity is started by startActivity with intent. Activity has a ui and life cycle.

`findviewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So if you are trying to initialize in `MainActivity` which is in `Settings` you get `NullPointerException`.

If you need the selected value from spinner you can use intent to pass values between activities.

You can use `SharedPreferences` also

Answer (score 0):

The method `onCreate` is called only when that particular activity is started at least one time. But as you are not even starting that `Settings` Activity, so the spinner you are trying to access will not be initialised as that spinner will not find the id that you are giving by `findViewByid(id)`. That is why you are getting **null pointer exception**.

And When you access that spinner after starting the `Settings` Activity then the spinner is able to find the id it is provided because `onCreate` method is called at least once.